# Is there a global flow on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with infinitesimal generator $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

1. Is there a global flow on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with infinitesimal generator $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

My answer:

Yes. I know that we’re looking for $\theta$ with velocity equals $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ at every point $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$. So

Let $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and $(x,y)$ is the starting point. We have

$\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}=-1$ and $\frac{d\theta_2}{dt} =0$.

Hence
$\theta_1(t)=c-t$ and since $\theta_1(0)=x$, we get $\theta_1=x-t$.

Similarly, $\theta_2=y$.

As a result, $\theta(x,y)=(x-t,y)$.

2. Is there a global flow on $M=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x>0\} $ with infinitesimal generator $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

I know that the answer is no, I am not sure how to prove it though. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $t\hspace{0pt}$?

Comment: Locally the flow on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and on its subset $M$ would have to be the same, wouldn't they? So ...?

Comment: @ElliotG $t$ is time. I added some details in my post.

Comment: For your second question, look for example at $\theta_t(1,0)=(1-t,0)$. So, for what values of $t$ does this lie in the set M?

Comment: @peek-a-boo when $t<1$?

Comment: Right, so the domain of definition is not the entire real numbers $\Bbb{R}$, it is only $(-\infty, 1)$. So that answers why the flow is not global/complete in the second scenario.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see! Thank you.